Issue with uploading to Digital Ocean spaces using nodejs
I'm trying to make a request to upload images to Digital Oceans Spaces but I get the below error
Error creating and publishing Instagram media: UnknownEndpoint: Inaccessible host:ndovu-dev-upload.your-space-region.digitaloceanspaces.com' at port undefined'. This service may not be available in the us-east-1' region.`
have tried to create a new Space on a different region but I'm getting the same error.
